# Start app if stopped

Tags: startup, mono

I made an application with Mono, and I want it is always running.
If my application stopped, I need it to automatically start again.
Does anyone have solution that would help me?

Also, how do I start an application at startup?

Comment: @PerlDuck: The second link in my previous comment covers just that.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the following approach:

Make a shell script to start the app again if it is stopped (make sure that it is marked as executable):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do
  mono /path/to/exe
done
```

The loop is paused each time the `mono` command is run, as it will wait for it to complete, so your app shouldn't launch hundreds of times.

Then, you can make it launch at logon.

1. Open the *Startup Applications* application. You can search for it in the dash.
2. Click add, and in the *Command* box, add the path to the shell script.

Log out, then log back in again, and hopefully your mono application should be running.